# How do I get rid of the remaining dashes that is more than the length of my attribute in select statement output?

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, sqlplus

```
SPOOL IT2T2SolutionOutputNN.txt
SET ECHO ON
SET FEEDBACK ON
SET LINESIZE 100
SET LINE 132
SET PAGESIZE 200
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON

create or replace procedure numberOfSupplier(X IN NUMBER) 
IS
supplierDetails SYS_REFCURSOR;
begin 

   open supplierDetails for
   select R_NAME, N_NAME, COUNT(S_NATIONKEY)
   from supplier
   inner join nation on supplier.s_nationkey = nation.n_nationkey
   inner join region on nation.n_regionkey = region.r_regionkey
   group by R_NAME, N_NAME
   having COUNT(S_NATIONKEY) > X;
   DBMS_SQL.RETURN_RESULT(supplierDetails);

end numberOfSupplier;
/
columns clear
execute numberOfSupplier(130)



SPOOL OFF
```

the output is:

```
ResultSet #1

R_NAME                    N_NAME                    COUNT(S_NATIONKEY)
------------------------- ------------------------- ------------------
ASIA                      INDONESIA                                131
ASIA                      CHINA                                    145
MIDDLE EAST               SAUDI ARABIA                             132
EUROPE                    GERMANY                                  132

4 rows selected.
```

I am trying to center the values in each row so I added the lpad function to the attribute "COUNT(S_NATIONKEY)":

```
select R_NAME, N_NAME, LPAD(COUNT(S_NATIONKEY), 10) as "COUNT(S_NATIONKEY)" etc...
```

so it becomes:

```
ResultSet #1

R_NAME                    N_NAME                    COUNT(S_NATIONKEY)
------------------------- ------------------------- ----------------------------------------
ASIA                      INDONESIA                        131
ASIA                      CHINA                            145
MIDDLE EAST               SAUDI ARABIA                     132
EUROPE                    GERMANY                          132

4 rows selected.
```

Can some help me get rid of the dashes behind "COUNT(S_NATIONKEY)"?

Comment: `HTML` would be a better option, for left alignment it uses `align=left`. It's more presentable and improved readability over traditional ASCII based reports.

Answer (score 0):

Give that expression an alias:

```
select (...), COUNT(S_NATIONKEY) as number_of_nationkeys
```

Then, before running query, set column's format (put that among all `SET`s you wrote) as

```
col number_of_nationkeys format 99999999999999999999
```

(number of 9s represents number of characters in "number_of_nationkeys"). Of course, it'll look prettier if you used shorter alias, e.g. `cnt_nat`; then you'd `col cnt_nat format 9999999`.

But, generally speaking, that's *how*.